# C++ Error getting the derived class to display a variable in a abstract class that has a aggregation relation with the parent of the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, aggregation

I'm trying to get my derived class(humanplayer) to make a variable member function of abstract(Vector) equal to "hi" so that I can display that but the compiler acts all weird and says EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef __testing_more_stuff__vector__
#define __testing_more_stuff__vector__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vector{//abstract class
public:
    void setName(string name_holder);
    virtual void test()=0;
protected:
    string name;

};

class player{//base class that has an aggregation relationship with vector

protected:
    Vector *molo;
};


class humanplayer:public player//derived class of player
{
public:
    void play();
};

#endif
```

Here is my implementation file:

```
#include "vector.h"

void Vector::setName(string name_holder)
{
    name=name_holder;
    cout<<name<<endl;
}

void humanplayer::play()
{
    molo->setName("hi");//since humanplayer inherits from player it should be able to set name to hi and print it out
}
```

Here is my test/main file:

```
#include "vector.h"


int main()
{
   humanplayer x;

   x.play();
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize molo? I ask because none of the code posted does that.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't understand why I would need to initialize molo. In fact i dont even know what I would initialize it too because its type is vector( the abstract class) so what value could it even be?

Comment: molo is a pointer to a Vector. You can not use molo until you point it to a Vector object.  You probably want to use new. ***so what value could it even be?*** Some random junk value that can crash your program when you try to dereference the uninitialized pointer molo.

Answer (score 1):

In `humanplayer::play()` you say:

```
molo->setName("hi")
```

However, `molo` is of type `Vector`, which is an abstract base class pointer.

A few things:

1. You don't have any concrete class that derives from `Vector`
2. You never initialize `molo` to something like `molo = new VectorDerivedClass()`
3. You don't default-initialize `molo` to `nullptr`, and you don't check for it. Your `string` assignment is undefined behavior.

You MUST have a concrete derived class from `Vector`. And you MUST instantiate the pointer with `new` before you try to do anything with it.

The nice thing about polymorphism is that you are allowed to have a pointer to an abstract base class. This pointer can be assigned to any dynamically allocated derived class. Effectively, the pointer enforces an interface; derived classes are guaranteed to implement the pure virtual functions in the abstract base (and inherit those you provide a definition for in the base).

The downside is that you do have to inherit from the class, and calls to `virtual` functions have to go through the virtual table (vtable), which is an indirection and is a tad bit slower.